# Build error - File google-services.json is missing from module root folder. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it

Tags: android

This is my directory structure for android project.

[image]

I tried putting google-services.json  file in all the folder one by one but could not solve the error.

Where should i put google-services.json file ?

Answer (score 0):

google-services.json file goes inside the top level `app` folder.  Right now you have it inside the `java` subfolder.